# mysql - select a column based on a combination of values from another column

Tags: php, mysql

hi i need to get the `plistid` based on a given combination of `avid`. For example i submitted a combination of 1 and 4 `avid`, it should return a `plistid` of 1. Another example is when i submitted a combination of 2 and 5 `avid` it should return a `plistid` of 5. And if i submitted 1 and 3 it should return nothing since they are of the same `attributeid`.

How can i generate it in mysql
here is my table
[image: property]

NOTE: avid can be a combination of 1,2,3 or 4 numbers depending on the number of avid's submitted.

Comment: It is unclear what your query logic is. Instead of all the *examples*, state the *rule*

Comment: I think he wants the `plistid` when it is same for both input, right?

Comment: i need to get the plistid based on a given combination of avid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find all the matches of `avid` by `plistid` and then check that they have different `attributeid`.  You can do this with aggregation, as a variation of a set-within-sets query:

```
select plistid
from t
group by plistid
having sum(avid = 1) > 0 and
       sum(avid = 4) > 0 and
       count(distinct case when avid in (1, 4) then attributeid end) = 2
```

The first two conditions in the `having` clause are saying what `avid`s you want.  They are counting the number of times that `avid` appears with one of the values, each returns true only when at least one value is found.  The last is saying that you need distinct attribute ids on the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select plistid
from t
where avid in (1,4)
group by plistid
having count(distinct avid) =2
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT t1.plistid 
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 
    ON t1.attributeid != t2.attributteid
    AND t1.plistid = t2.plistid
WHERE 
    t1.avid = 1
    AND t2.avid = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:-

```
select a.plistid 
from your_table a, your_table b
where a.plistid = b.plistid
and a.avid = <first param>
and b.avid = <second param>
and a.attributeid <> b.attributeid;
```